# Implicit Function Theorem for $\mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to learn the Implicit Function Theorem and I just want to be sure I am understanding this process correctly:

Let $F=(f_1,f_2)$, where $f_1(u,v,x,y,z)=xy^5+yu^5+zv^5-1$ and $f_2(u,v,x,y,z)=x^5y+y^5u+z^5v-1$. Show $u,v$ can be solved in terms of $x,y,z$ at $(1,0,0,1,1)$ and for good measure find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,1,1)$.

My attempt: I took the partials to get the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y^5 & 5xy^4-u^5 & v^5 & -5yu^4 & 5zv^4 \\
5x^4y & x^5+5y^4u & 5z^4v & y^5 & z^5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Note that all these partials are continuous everywhere, then $F$ is $C^1$ everywhere - in particular at $(1,0,0,1,1)$. It is routine to verify $F(1,0,0,1,1)=(0,0)$. We look now at the $u,v$ partials, we have the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-5yu^4 & 5zv^4 \\
y^5 & z^5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so at $(1,0,0,1,1)$ we have
$$
\text{det}
\begin{pmatrix}
-5 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
=-5\neq 0
$$
so that we can solve for $u,v$ in terms of $x,y,z$ at $(1,0,0,1,1)$. Finally, we have
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= -\frac{\text{det}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}}{\text{det}
\begin{pmatrix}
-5 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}}= \frac{1}{5}
$$
Is this correct? Or if not, where have I gone awry?

Comment: @S.W.Cheung Thank you! I did the same thing on the rewrite but when I originally copied the problem I couldn't remember the order the problem said so I just did $(x,y,z,u,v)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all looks correct to me. Congrats!